# Anatomy of a Java program

Tags: java, methods, parameters, field, local-variables

What is the terminology for each expression in the following class :

for e.g :

```
class Test {
    int a=0;
    void method(boolean boo){
        String b="";
        try
        {
            new Thread().sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){}
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"test");
        BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\file.png"));
    }
}
```

From what i know `a` is a *field*, `boo` is a *parameter*, `b` and `image` are *local variables*.

What is the terminology used for

1. `new Thread().sleep()`
2. `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`
3. `ImageIO.read()`
4. `new File()`
5. `InterruptedException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **`new Thread().sleep()` :**

This is a two-part expression. The first part i.e, `new Thread()` is actually documented in the [Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) as an unqualified class instance creation expression :

> Class instance creation expressions have two forms:
>
> Unqualified class instance creation expressions begin with the
>   keyword new.
>
> An unqualified class instance creation expression may be used to
>   create an instance of a class, regardless of whether the class is a
>   top level (§7.6), member (§8.5, §9.5), local (§14.3), or anonymous
>   class (§15.9.5).

You basically create an instance of the `Thread` class when you say `new Thread()`. The second part of the statement is `.sleep()` which is known as a method call.

### **`new File()` :**

This is also an unqualified class instance creation expression just like the expression `new Thread()` but creates an instance of the `File` class instead of the `Thread` class.

### **`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` :**

If you take a look at the source code for the [JOptionPane.showMessageDialog](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) method, you will see that the method is a `static` method. Also, the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) explains how to access static methods :

> A class method is always invoked without reference to a particular object.

What the JLS indirectly says is that you can access a `static` method outside the class in which it is defined using the name of the class.

Another important fact to understand here is that there are well defined Java naming conventions.

1. Class names start with an upper case and any subsequent words are capitalized. So when you see any text of the form `XyzAbc`, assume that it is either a `class` or an `interface`. For example, `JOptionPane` and `Image` are class names.
2. Similarly, there is also a convention in place for method names known as camel case. For example, whenever you see text such as `doSomething`, `getSomething`, `setSomething`, `showMessageDialog()`.. you should know that it is a method.

Putting all this understanding together, we can deduce that `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` calls a `static` method from `JOptionPane`.

### **`InterruptedException` :**

If you understood the naming conventions explained above, you should know by now that `InterruptedException` is a `class`. How it differs from any other class in `Java` is that it can be thrown around using the `throw` clause and then caught using a `try-catch` statement. You can read more about exception handling in the [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) documentation.

Answer (score 6):

[`new Thread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread--) is a constructor call. You are immediately calling `sleep` on the instance. This is odd, since `sleep` is a static method, so you can just do [`Thread.sleep(1000)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) for a static call (making sure to catch and handle `InterruptedException`.

[`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) is a static method call as is [`ImageIO.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-). [`new File()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-) is a constructor call that returns a `File` object.

Just a word on naming conventions: Field names (that aren't `static final` constants), variable names, and method names should be `camelCase` while class names should be `PascalCase`.

Answer (score 1):

You might also need pay attention to the top of the program, you will find that String, Thread (you usually may not see those two),JOptionPane , ImageIO and BufferedImage are imported from somewhere.

For being programming better, you need follow the naming convention please look at this:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Also please put modifiers in front of your class variables and methods